# Can Visual Studio installe with ms sql server be used to modify a .net windows app?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to modify a .net written in visual  studio 2008. However, when I loaded and try to build the website, I get a bunch of errors that several controls like firstname.text are not declared even though the app has been working.

It is possible that I am getting this error because I am using the BI version fo visual studio?

Thanks alot for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible.  If I understand correctly, you're using BIDS to modify a .NET project.

Business Intelligence Studio is a completely different program than Visual Studio (though they are based on the same editor).  If you want to modify the .NET project, you will need an Instance of Visual Studio, not BIDS (Business Intelligence Developer Studio).